# Create a variable based on file in folder

Tags: variables, batch-file

Every Friday night a file is going to be placed in a directory.  I am writing a batch file to archive the file (with a simple Copy command) and then I need to rename and load the file into an OLAP database.  Unfortunately, I don't know what the filename will be each week since it's based on a date and time stamp - the only thing I know is that will end in `.txt`.

Since this will be the only file in the folder, is it possible to create a variable based on the filename?

This is what I've got so far:

```
if not exist "%LoadFolder%\*.txt" (
    rem Send email notification that the latest Exchange Rates file does not exist...
    "E:\Programs\PuTTY\plink.exe" -v -ssh servername -pw password /u02/hyp_app/Scripts/STFC/STFC_File_Not_Exist.ksh
    exit
) else (
    rem 1) Copy latest file to Archive folder...
    FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%LoadFolder%\*.txt" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
    copy "%Load%\%NewestFile%" "%LoadFolder%\Archive\%NewestFile%"

    rem 2) Rename the latest file to Load_File.txt...
    FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "%LoadFolder%\*.txt" /B /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
    REN "%LoadFolder%\%NewestFile%" "Load_File.txt"
)

REM rest of code..........
```

The issue I have is that the folder is being renamed to Load_File as opposed to the file within the folder.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Pls edit your question, use CODE button to format your code properly in the Text Window.

Comment: [Debugging your batch files](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_debugging.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *Archive* folder exists, try this script and post exact error if any. Replace *yourFolderPath* with your real folder path:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set LoadFolder=yourFolderPath
if not exist "%LoadFolder%\*.txt" (
rem Send email notification that the latest Exchange Rates file does not exist...
"E:\Programs\PuTTY\plink.exe" -v -ssh servername -pw password /u02/hyp_app/Scripts/STFC/STFC_File_Not_Exist.ksh
) else ( rem Copy latest file to Archive folder and rename it at source dir
    FOR %%I IN ("%LoadFolder%\*.txt") DO (
        copy %%I "%LoadFolder%\Archive\%%~nxI"
        ren %%I Load_File%%~xI ))
timeout 5
exit /b
```

Read more on [path modifiers](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) in *SS64 Cmd Reference*.

Comment: sambul35, thanks for your help.  Your code appears to be working.